# loading pref showConsoleLogs before prefs were initialised, you will not get the correct result

Tags: javascript, wordpress, content-script

CMS - wordpress
after some changes i have error on one page:

**loading pref showConsoleLogs before prefs were initialised, you will not get the correct result  content-script.bundle.js:333**

http://www.74skazka.ru/restorany/baden-gourmet/?donotcachepage=84523706ac5384c08c3beb52312fdef0

if i delete all code error anyway here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Ghostery extension causes a similar issue for me, but you didn't include the full logs, so can't be sure

Comment: Have the same on http://jcubic.pl, and that's all the logs, just the warning with link to source code for content-script.bundle.js. I have this waring showing up 8 times. Probably for each blocked script.

Answer (score 1):

The error itself should be harmless. It is an internal error message that comes from [prefs.es](https://github.com/cliqz-oss/browser-core/blob/master/platforms/webextension/prefs.es#L35), which is used by the Ghostery extension and the Cliqz extension.

There is an open bug report:
https://github.com/ghostery/ghostery-extension/issues/135

Until a fix is released, it is safe for you to ignore the message, as it does not indicate a problem in your website.